# unable to call a stored variable in shell script

Tags: shell, variables, echo, store, sh

I have a very basic script that starts with saving part of input argument to a varialbe:

```
dirN= basename $1
echo $dirN
```

$dirN was displayed as expected
then I try to cat a string with $dirN

```
tmp="/some/path/$dirN"
```

when I echo $tmp, it only displays /some/path/

I tried overwriting tmp

```
tmp=$dirN
```

and echo $tmp,
it shows nothing.
it's like $dirN was never stored, but it was echoed from line 2
I am very confused, so was my colleague.

Any hint?

Thank you all!

Comment: `dirN= basename $1` does not assign anything to dirN.  Rather, it executes `basename` with `dirN` set to the null string in its environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want

```
dirN=`basename $1`
```

to actually store the value returned instead of

```
dirN= basename $1
```

The "echo $dirN" is not showing anything in your version, it's the previous line that shows the output you attribute to the echo.